# to_datetime() to display the ouput in a specific format

Tags: python, pandas

A column in my dataframe stores dates.
I first converted it to datetime type by :

```
test['date'] = pd.to_datetime(test['date'])
```

Now this displays the timestamp as well.
To remove the timestamp I did :

```
test['date'] = pd.to_datetime(test['date']).dt.date
```

But as soon as I run this command, the dtype of test['date'], which was **dtype('<M8[ns]')**, converted back to **dtype('O')**.

ALso, the date originally was '**1/29/2022**' now gets stored as '**2022-01-29**' after using pd.to_datetime().

**Is there a way to store it as **1/29/2022** but the dtype should be datetime?**

Comment: You should not have to worry about how the datetime object is represented, this is internal. What matters is that you can use the object's properties/methods. In the final step you can chose to convert back to string for export. Can you give a reproducible example?

Comment: @mozwaythis needs to be exported to a csv after some data manipulation and needs to be saved a date. Also, I want to sort the data according to dates in ascending order.

Comment: Thus my comment on separating the processing (use datetime) and export (use strings). But if you need help, please provide a full reproducible example for clarity.

Comment: Use pandas.Series.dt.strftime.

Comment: @mozway gotit. thanks. One more thing tho. The first 10 rows have date as 2022-01-01. The next 10 rows have date as 2022-01-02. And so on. After 100 rows, again the date starts from 2022-01-01. 
when I do test.sort_values(by='date',inplace=True), the first row at index 0 remains at the top. but the second row is the row which was at index 101. How is it getting sorted? Shouldn't the 1st ten rows which have the date as 2022-01-01 be at the top, then the rows from below which had date as the same?

Comment: Not necessarily, not all sorting methods are stable (use `method='stable'` to force it)

Comment: @mozway It's giving me this error : TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'

Comment: sorry, it's `kind`, not `method`, but I guess this means you have not read the [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) documentation ;) **You should!**